# The for loop in my last function does not seem to be executing. I coded an example version and it ran just fine so I don't understand the issue

Tags: python, list, function, for-loop

The full code for the program is below, it selects a random word based on the letters in the user's initial input and then is suppose to create a phrase saying, for example, x is for xylophone. The problem issue is the last function, the string variable 'phrase' is not being appended to the list 'phrases'.

```py
from random import choice
import re
from time import sleep
from nltk.corpus import words

# This code takes user word and creates list of separate letters
user_letters = []
def get_letters():
   acrostiche = input("Enter your word here: ").upper()
   for letter in acrostiche:
      user_letters.append(letter)

# This code finds a random word for each letter in list user_letters
beginning_words = list()
user_letters2 = user_letters
def get_words_to_start_lines():
   while len(user_letters2) > 0:
      for letter in user_letters2:
         lettered_words = list(re.findall(letter + r".*", words.raw("en")))
         word = choice(lettered_words)
         lettered_words.clear
         break
      beginning_words.append(word)
      user_letters2.remove(letter)

# this code should generate a list of phrases user_letter is for beginning_word for each letter and word
phrases = list()
user_letters3 = [i for i in user_letters]
beginning_words2 = [ i for i in beginning_words]
def beginning_phrases():
   while len(user_letters3) > 0 and len(beginning_words2) > 0:
      for word in beginning_words2:
         for letter in user_letters3:
            phrase = letter + "is for" + word
      user_letters3.remove(letter)
      beginning_words2.remove(word)
      phrases.append(phrase)
   print(phrases)

get_letters()
print(user_letters)

get_words_to_start_lines()
print(beginning_words)
sleep(2)

beginning_phrases()
```

Here is some sample output:

```
Enter your word here: hi
['H', 'I']
['Hierochloe', 'Ita']
[]
```

The final two brackets represent the list named `phrases`, as you can see, nothing has been appended to it. Again, I have tried coding a simple example in a separate file which worked which I will share below.

```py
numbers = ['1', '2', '3']
words = ['cat', 'dogs', 'mice']
phrases = []
def example():
    while len(words) > 0 and len(numbers) > 0:
        for w in words:
            for n in numbers:
                phrase = n + w
        numbers.remove(n)
        words.remove(w)
        phrases.append(phrase)
    print(phrases)

print(numbers)
print(words)
example()
```

The sample output for this is as such:

```
['1', '2', '3']
['cat', 'dogs', 'mice']
['3mice', '2dogs', '1cat']
```

Comment: `user_letters2.remove(letter)` is removing the letters from `user_letters`. `user_letters2` is not a copy, it's the same list.

Comment: I have tried making two copies of the user_letters list using two methods: user_letters2 = [i for i in user_letters] and user_letters3 = user_letters.copy() but these both return blank lists too.

Comment: It doesn't matter, but `lettered_words.clear` doesn't do anything, since it's missing `()`. But there's no need to clear the list between iterations.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I managed to sort it by creating a copy of the list within each function rather than outside them and thanks for the heads up on the typo. I appreciate it.

Comment: You're setting `user_letters3` and `beginning_words2` before you call the functions that fill in `user_letters` and `beginning_words`, so you're making copies of empty lists.

Comment: Thank you, that makes a lot of sense. You've been quite helpful.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the answer above, the line `user_letters2.remove(letter)` is outside the scope of the for loop that defines `letter`.

Comment: Python loops don't create a new scope.

Comment: Maybe I was using non-Python terminology, but I was referring to that line of code being improperly indented so that it executes outside the `for` loop instead of within it.

Comment: That may be a problem, but it's not what's causing his empty lists.